# How to bundle asset for mobile apps only and not for Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to build a Flutter app with support for custom fonts. The quirk is, I ideally only want to bundle the fonts in mobile apps and not on Web without making significant changes to code at build time.
Is there any method?

I added Font Files into assets and pubspec, also used the package google_fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

Create two folders in your project directory: fonts and fonts_web.

Add your font files to the fonts folder.

Update your pubspec.yaml file to include the font files in the assets section:

yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - fonts/
```

Then you need to Install google_fonts package to make it easy and smooth to use custom fonts in your app:

yaml

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

Then nn your code, import google_fonts package, and use GoogleFonts widget to specify custom font:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

For including the fonts only for mobile apps, you need use conditional imports based on platform. Then Replace the assets section in pubspec.yaml file with the code shown below :

yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - ${{false ? "ignore" : "fonts/"}}
    - ${{true ? "fonts_web/" : "ignore/"}}
```

Create the fonts_web folder, add an empty ignore file in it. It will prevent your fonts from being included in the web builds.

Comment: <code> 
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - {{false ? "ignore" : "assets/fonts/" }}
    - {{true ? "assets/fonts_web/" : "ignore/" }}
</code>
I created 2 folders "fonts" and "fonts_web" under assets folder. So the code is like that, right?